# ExpandoObject vs. Dictionary from a performance point of view?

Tags: c#, dictionary, expandoobject

A rather simple question really. I'm working on a project where I need to store and retrieve property values dynamically from a kind of context storage. The values will be written now and then and read multiple times. Speed of retrieval is the top priority here, and every nanosecond counts.

Usually, I'd simply implement this with a Dictionary, but with C# 4 and the ExpandoObject I'm thinking that maybe there is a better way? Does anyone have any experience with it? I've seen in other posts that it is NOT implemented using a Dictionary, which makes me curious as to whether it is quicker or slower?

Let me try to clarify with some pseudo code:

```
// In the main loop
var context = new Context();
context["MyKey"] = 123;
context["MyOtherKey"] = "CODE";
context["MyList"] = new List<int>() { 1, 12, 14 };

foreach(var handler in handlers) {
    handler.DoStuff(context);
}
```

-

```
// "Handlers"
class MyFirstHandler {
     void DoStuff(Context context) {
          if (context["MyKey"] > 100)
               context["NewKey"] = "CODE2";
     }
}

class MySecondHandler {
     void DoStuff(Context context) {
          if (context["MyOtherKey"] == "CODE")
             context["MyList"].Add(25); // Remember, it's only Pseudo-code..
     }
}
```

Well, hopefully you get what I'm trying to do..

I'm also completely open to other suggestions here. I have been toying with the idea of making the Context class statically typed (i.e. actually having a `MyKey` property, a `MyOtherKey` property etc), and while it might be possible it would hinder productivity quite a lot for us.

Comment: It looks like you have a lot of string constants, does this mean you have a list of your dictionary keys ahead of time? If so, just use a vanilla class to avoid the overhead of your hash function.

Comment: Yes, I actually only used the string constants to simplify the pseudo code. In the "current" real-world example I'm using faster keys.

Comment: [Here's a simple comparison](http://spiritofdev.blogspot.in/2011/12/performance-of-c-40-dynamic-vs.html). If you can ignore the construction cost, the lookups should perform similarly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Speed of retrieval is the top priority here, and every nanosecond counts.

Anything to do with `dynamic` probably *isn't* what you're looking for then...

Don't get me wrong, it's pretty heavily optimised - but if you *basically* just want a string-to-string dictionary lookup, stick with a dictionary.

Alternatively, if you have a limited number of keys, have you considered just having an array with either an enum or a bunch of `int` constants as the keys?

Comment: Thank's, that was kind of what I expected (but not what I was hoping for..) I think the problem with a simple array would be pretty much the same as if I'd go with statically typing the Context class, i.e. I need a central location that knows about all the possible keys. It could be done, but I would prefer to have a more flexible approach.

Comment: @CodingInsomnia: If you don't want to have a limited set of keys then the `Dictionary<,>` is definitely the way to go - but don't hard-code the keys as string literals in the code using them... have string constants instead, to avoid typos.

Comment: Yeah, absolutely. I'm actually not going to use strings at all for keys, that was just to simplify the psuedo code.

Comment: I know it's quiet an old thread, but if I have a json data that I load every time it changes via an API. This data is  representing a udp datagram, that may have number of variables with their type and possible value. I want to on the fly create a datagram object with header payload info. But I am wondering how will performance be if Everytime I have to parse the  byte array from machine and send back to higher Apis as json and then get back the json and parse back to byte before sending it to machine. Every such cycle can be up to milliseconds. What would be better option? Dynamic object?

Comment: Via .net core 3.1..  One is to serialize and deserialze data based on dynamic json.  For both header and payload. I am a little concerned about performance should the payload be serialized and deserialzed every cycle.

Comment: @kuldeep: I suggest you ask a new question with as much context as you can, ideally with a complete example.

Answer (score 3):

If the list of strings is known in advance, you could use IL Emit to create a branching tree based on the characters in the search string and resolve to an index into an array.  This should give you pretty fast lookup speed.

I implemented something like this for fun and practice while I was learning IL Emit.  It works based on the limited test cases I've tried, but you'll definitely want to make it more robust and create proper unit tests for production code.  I've posted the raw code (it's a tad long); you'd need to change a few things for your particular case, but the core logic is there.  I didn't include the `EmitLdc` helper function (there are a lot of overloads), but it's just a function to load an arbitrary constant to the stack.  You can simply replace the calls to emit the string and numeric types directly using Ldstr and Ldc_I4 respectively.

```
    protected void GenerateNestedStringSearch<T>(ILGenerator gen, T[] values, Func<T, string> getName, Action<ILGenerator, T> loadValue)
    {
        //We'll jump here if no match found
        Label notFound = gen.DefineLabel();

        //Try to match the string
        GenerateNestedStringSearch(gen, notFound, values, getName, loadValue, 0);

        //Nothing found, so don't need string anymore
        gen.MarkLabel(notFound);
        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Pop);

        //Throw ArgumentOutOfRangeException to indicate not found
        gen.EmitLdc("name");
        gen.EmitLdc("Binding does not contain a tag with the specified name: ");
        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Call, typeof(String).GetMethod("Concat",
                                                        BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public,
                                                        null,
                                                        new[] { typeof(string), typeof(string) },
                                                        null));
        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Newobj,
                 typeof(ArgumentOutOfRangeException).GetConstructor(new[] { typeof(string), typeof(string) }));
        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Throw);
    }

    protected void GenerateNestedStringSearch<T>(ILGenerator gen, Label notFound, T[] values, Func<T, string> getName, Action<ILGenerator, T> loadValue, int charIndex)
    {
        //Load the character from the candidate string for comparison
        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Dup);
        gen.EmitLdc(charIndex);
        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldelem_U2);

        //Group possible strings by their character at this index
        //We ignore strings that are too short
        var strings = values.Select(getName).ToArray();
        var stringsByChar =
            from x in strings
            where charIndex < x.Length
            group x by x[charIndex]
                into g
                select new { FirstChar = g.Key, Strings = g };

        foreach (var grouped in stringsByChar)
        {
            //Compare source character to group character and jump ahead if it doesn't match
            Label charNotMatch = gen.DefineLabel();
            gen.Emit(OpCodes.Dup);
            gen.EmitLdc(grouped.FirstChar);
            gen.Emit(OpCodes.Bne_Un, charNotMatch);

            //If there is only one string in this group, we've found our match
            int count = grouped.Strings.Count();
            Debug.Assert(count > 0);
            if (count == 1)
            {
                //Don't need the source character or string anymore
                gen.Emit(OpCodes.Pop);
                gen.Emit(OpCodes.Pop);

                //Return the value for this name
                int index = Array.FindIndex(strings, s => s == grouped.Strings.First());
                loadValue(gen, values[index]);
                gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
            }
            else
            {
                //Don't need character anymore
                gen.Emit(OpCodes.Pop);

                //If there is a string that ends at this character
                string endString = grouped.Strings.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Length == (charIndex + 1));
                if (endString != null)
                {
                    //Get string length
                    gen.Emit(OpCodes.Dup);
                    gen.Emit(OpCodes.Call, typeof(char[]).GetProperty("Length").GetGetMethod());

                    //If string length matches ending string
                    gen.EmitLdc(endString.Length);
                    Label keepSearching = gen.DefineLabel();
                    gen.Emit(OpCodes.Bne_Un, keepSearching);

                    //Don't need the source string anymore
                    gen.Emit(OpCodes.Pop);

                    //Create an UnboundTag for this index
                    int index = Array.FindIndex(strings, s => s == endString);
                    loadValue(gen, values[index]);
                    gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

                    //String length didn't match
                    gen.MarkLabel(keepSearching);
                }

                //Need to consider strings starting with next character
                var nextValues = from s in grouped.Strings
                                 join v in values on s equals getName(v) 
                                 select v;

                GenerateNestedStringSearch(gen, notFound, nextValues.ToArray(),
                    getName, loadValue, charIndex + 1);
            }

            //This character didn't match, so consider next character
            gen.MarkLabel(charNotMatch);
        }

        //We don't need the character anymore
        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Pop);

        //No string match, so jump to Not Found at end of check
        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Br, notFound);
    }
```

---

EDIT: I just realized that you're not actually using string keys, so this may not be applicable to your case.  You could use a similar technique with other look ups as long as you have the ability to collect all of the required keys together in advance of using them.  I'll keep this here in case anybody else might find it useful.

Comment: Since he is using C# 4.0, he could use Expression Trees to build statements.

I wrote a post about it for a while ago (statements is a the bottom of it):
http://translate.google.com/translate?js=y&prev=_t&hl=sv&ie=UTF-8&layout=1&eotf=1&u=http%3A%2F%2Fweblogs.asp.net%2Fmikaelsoderstrom%2Farchive%2F2009%2F09%2F27%2Ff-246-rst-229-expression-trees.aspx&sl=sv&tl=en

I wrote it in swedish, which is why I have a link to Google Translate. :)

Comment: +1 for a really creative answer - probably won't be able to use it, but still..!

Answer (score 2):

Does it have to be that fast at the first call? Thanks to the call site cache, the expression trees created for the dynamic object (including the methods you add to it) is cached after it´s compiled and will be returned when you use it again.

Using ExpandoObject should work, but if you really need to get the absolutely best performance, maybe you should use custom types.

Comment: That sounds very interesting. It is not crucial that the first call is extremely quick, each property will typically be called a LOT of times so if retrieving a value could be quicker than from a Dictionary it may be worth it. I guess I'll just have to try a few different methods..

Comment: The best thing to do is just to populate it with a lot of dummy data and see which method is the fastest. :)